# Add Comment to User and Post models Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have microposts that belong to artists, and everything with that works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to let artists comment on microposts. However, this isn't working how I want it. The comments need to belong to both a specific artist and a specific micropost.

Right now I have a form to create a comment, but it only saves under the most recent micropost id.

```
### controllers/artists/comments_controller.rb ###

class Artists::CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @micropost = ArtistMicropost.find_by(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.artist_micropost_comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.artist_id = current_artist.id
  end

    private

      def comment_params
        params.require(:artist_micropost_comment).permit(:artist_micropost_id, :artist_id, :content)
      end

end

### controllers/artists/artists_controller.rb ###

class Artists::ArtistsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = ArtistMicropost.new
    @micro = ArtistMicropost.find_by(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = ArtistMicropostComment.new
  end

end

### views/artists/show.html.erb ###

<% @artist.artist_microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  ...
  <%= micropost.content %>
  ...

  <% @micro.artist_micropost_comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.submit "post comment" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

### models/artist.rb ###

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artist_micropost_comments, dependent: :destroy
end

### models/artist_micropost.rb ###

class ArtistMicropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :artist_micropost_comments, dependent: :destroy
end

### models/artist_micropost_comment.rb ###

class ArtistMicropostComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist_micropost
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

I want it to display each micropost by the artist and underneath each micropost to display the comments that belong to the micropost. I the want the from to display under the comments to add new comments. Basically, I want it to look something like Facebook.

Right now, all the comments are displaying under each micropost no matter what the micropost_id and the create method won't create under any micropost_id, except the most recent one.

So my two problems are:

I can't get the comments to save under the correct micropost_id

I can't get the comments to loop for their micropost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add information about how `Artist`, `ArtistMicroPost`, and `ArtistMicropostComment` models are related please?

Comment: Yes, added them just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short names are easier to read and understand so I will rename your models in my example to `Artist`, `Micropost` and `Comment`

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, through: :microposts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # I renamed artist to commenter to make it clear that is not the same artist as the one that created the micropost,
  # this implies that instead of author_id you will have commented_id in comments table

  belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => Artist
  belongs_to :micropost
end


### views/artists/show.html.erb ###

<% @artist.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  ...
  <%= micropost.content %>
  ...


  <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
    # here you display comments for each micropost
    <%= comment.content %>

    # pay attention at the way I builded the comment
    <%= form_for(micropost.comments.build) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id %> # this will make the link to your micropost
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
      <%= f.submit "post comment" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your `comments_controller` you must assign current logged in artist (the commenter) to your comment.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.commenter = current_artist

    if @comment.save
      ...
    end 
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:micropost_id, :content)
  end
end
```

To avoid N+1 when you load artists, microposts and commenters do something like this:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @artist = Artist.includes(:microposts, :comments => :commenter).find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For Your requirement. For creation of microposts.
do something like this.

```
artist=Artist who is logged in
artist.artist_micro_posts.build(attributes)
artist.save
```

For creating comments to microposts

```
micro_posts= Micropost Id
 micro_post.artist_micropost_comments.build(:artist_id=logged in person)
micro_post.save
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between this and what I already have.